# Finding derivatives by solving for y'

Tags: calculus

Here's the hyperlink for the picture:

[image]

On step 6.) where the differentiation happens, can someone explain why...

$$(\ln|y|)' = \frac{1}{y} \cdot y'$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply the chain rule. It might be more clear what's happening when you write it in Leibniz notation:
$$\frac{d}{dx} (\ln|y|) = \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot \frac{d}{dy} (\ln|y|) $$
$$ \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx} (\ln|y|) = \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot \frac{1}{y}$$
Which in prime notation is just $(\ln|y|)' = (1/y) \cdot y'$.

Definitely would recommend brushing up on the chain rule here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule